# How to make use of value of state in a child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to find the best way I can make use of the value of a state in a child component. The idea is to create a setting-component with a state that can be updated by user input, and this updated value can then be used to alter the result of some calculations in another component. I have tried Redux, but I can't just get it to work.

I have a form that collects the user data

```
 class SettingModal extends Component {
     constructor(props){
      super(props);
       this.state={
           open:false,
           value: '',
       }
     }
     handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({value: e.target.value}, () =>
        this.props.valueDispatcher(this.state.value),
      )
    }

    render() {
        const { open } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Button variant="link"
                className="promo-code-button"

          onClick={() => this.setState({ open: !open })}
          aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
          aria-expanded={open}
        >
         {open === false? <Button

color="primary"
block
className="btn-round"
         >
Overtime rate Settings
         </Button>:<Button
         color="primary"
         block
         className="btn-round"
         >
             Close overtime Settings
             </Button>} 


        </Button>

         <Collapse in={open}>
         <div id="example-collapse-text">
         <Row className="show-grid">
         <Col md={12}>
         <Form>
  <Form.Group controlId="formInlineName">
    <Form.Label>Enter overtime rate and click apply...</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="type here" 
 value={this.state.value}
 onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">

    </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>
  <Button
  block
  variant="success"

  disabled={this.props.isDisabled}
  onClick={this.props.giveDiscount}
  >Apply</Button>
  </Form>
         </Col>


         </Row>


         </div>

         </Collapse>

        </>
   );
}
}
```

And this is a dispatch component

```
import { React, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import WagesSettingModal from './WagesSettingModal';
import WagesCalculator7 from './WagesCalculator7';

function OvertimeRateValue (props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('Initial')

  const handleChange = useCallback(e => setValue(e.target.value), [])

  return (
    <div>
      < WagesSettingModal valueDispatcher={setValue} />
      <WagesCalculator value={value}/>
    </div>
  )
}


export default OvertimeRateValue;
```

And lastly, I make use of that value here

```
import React from 'react'
Imported above component from './above component'

 renderTable() {


    var totalCount = 0;
    var shownCount = 0;
    var lowerBound = 0;
    var upperBound = 0;
    var filtered = [];

    filtered = this.state.data.map( (row, i,) => {
      if(row.department.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.departmentFilter) > -1){
        return (
          <tr key={"employeeData"+i}>
            <td>{i+1}</td>

            <td>{row.name}</td>
            <td>{row.numberofPresentAttendances}</td>
            <td>{row.department}</td>
            <td>{row.wages}</td>


            <td>
            <Link to={"/employee/overtime/"+row._id}>
                <Button className="btn btn-light"><Overtime/></Button>
              </Link>

            </td>
            <td>{row.overtime}</td>
            <td>{row.totalWages}</td>
            <td>


              {row.overtime<1? row.numberofPresentAttendances * row.wages* 8
            : row.numberofPresentAttendances * [row.wages* 8]+[row.wages*<above component/>]*row.overtime}

            </td>



            <td>


            </td>
          </tr>
        );
```

My goal istobe able to change the outcome of the result of the calculation by varying the number input by user

Comment: A working demo is worth than a length code :). can you create a simple fiddle

Comment: okay,will do that

Comment: I know you dont want to hear this, but you really should look again at redux. Data does not move backwards in React, it has to come from the top level and gets passed down. Redux wraps your upper level components and passes data down to where ever you need them. What you are trying to do here is re-invent the wheel, badly. It would be worth your time getting to know the tools which already exist.

Comment: @TPHughes thank you for giving me the courage (smiles) I will try Redux once more